# How do I show a hidden div using jQuery Toggle?

Tags: jquery

I have a portfolio section I am building on a page that displays a thumbnail of an image. I also have a hidden div that contains information about the portfolio project that I would like to show when a user mouses over the thumbnail.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><img src="photos/work_2.jpg" alt="work_1" width="181" height="180"></a>
    <div class="portfolio-overlay" style="display:none;">
        <p class="client-name">Encore Azalea</p>
        <div class="white-line"></div>
        <p class="services">website redesign +<br />mobile site launch</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
$(".portfolio a").hover(function () {
$(".portfolio-overlay").toggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

My intent is to display .portfolio-overlay when you mouse over the image and hide it when you mouse out.

I know there is something missing with the jQuery but, if I knew what it was, I wouldn't be posting this (you know how it goes).

Thanks.

Comment: works fine here.. what isn't working ? http://jsfiddle.net/Q42RD/

Comment: Try putting your code in a [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for me too. What is it that is not working?

Comment: Since it's an overlay, I would suggest checking your CSS z-index and position for `.portfolio-overlay` because the code looks fine and others report it working.

Comment: The page is available to view here: http://rouviere.com/clients/optera/ Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.portfolio a:has(>img)').hover(function(e){
  var $overlay = $(this).siblings('.portfolio-overlay');
  $overlay.toggle('slow');
},function(e){
  var $overlay = $(this).siblings('.portfolio-overlay');
  $overlay.toggle('slow');
});
```

Something that that perhaps? Since you're starting at the anchor you can reference `.siblings()` and find the overlay that's within the same `.portfolio`, then toggle it accordingly. This also makes each `.portfolio` run independent of others on the page, where as using `$('.portfolio-overlay')` will toggle all the items on the page.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/AhnGA/1/

Comment: Hi Brad, you comment makes sense. I have uploaded it to a server for viewing: http://rouviere.com/clients/optera/

Comment: @fmz: Wrap it in a `$(document).ready(function(){` and `});` as long as it's in the `<head>` of the document, otherwise make sure it's the last element before `</body>`.

Comment: Hi, we are making progress. I added the $(document).ready portion, however, when I mouse over it, it fades in an quickly fades out. Perhaps it needs something besides hover for the hide again part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @fmz: It gets a little tricky when the child element takes over the original element's real estate, but something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/CmZgp/) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for taking so much time to help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot document ready function,

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".portfolio a").hover(function () {
        $(".portfolio-overlay").toggle("slow");
      });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, this is very close, but Brad above makes an important point. Thanks.